# Want answer of this 8086 assembly code and values of AL,BL and status flags after every instruction?

Tags: x86-16

Unable to find the values of status register.
I have download the emulator of 8086 assembly language.I it shows error in line SBB and asking for more operands.

```
    STC
    MOV AL,4CH
    SBB
    XOR BL,BL
    MOV [SI],BL
    HLT
```

Comment: Is there a standalone version of SBB: http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/sbb.htm

Comment: May be. but not confirm. This question is given to me in my microprocessor exam.

Comment: There is no zero-operand form of subtract-with-borrow in standard x86 assembly. Does your class use an unusual assembler perhaps? If not there is as error in the code.

Comment: Yup...it is a vmc 8069 microprocessor kit. where it is working as said by my teacher..

Comment: Maybe you should set the title right then...